# TButton on firemonkey form not showing on android

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a regular TButton on a firemonkey form.  In the form's FormShow event I adjust the button width with the following line of code:

```
Button1->Width = Form1->ClientWidth * 0.8;
```

The button shows up fine on iOS and is sized properly. On Android the button just doesn't show up.  I changed my code to the following and it works fine on Android (and iOS).

```
Button1->Width = Screen->Width * 0.8;
```

I'd like to understand why the first line of code doesn't work on Android.  Note, if i use either line of code in the form's FormPaint event it works fine.  Obviously this isn't urgent - i'd just like to know why the first line of code fails in FormShow.

Comment: Did you check to see whether `Form1->ClientWidth` is 0 in the `OnShow` event? `OnShow` tends to be fired before the Form is actually visible onscreen.  Also, you shouldn't be using `Form1->` from inside of `Form1`'s own methods, rely on the implicit `this` pointer instead, eg: `Button1->Width = this->ClientWidth * 0.8;` or simply `Button1->Width = ClientWidth * 0.8;` If `ClientWidth` is not available yet in `OnShow`, delay the assignment until after `OnShow` exits. You could use `TThread::ForceQueue()` for that, eg: `TThread::ForceQueue(nullptr, [this](){Button1->Width = ClientWidth * 0.8;});`

Comment: Remy - thank you.  That was the deal - ClientWidth was 0 like you suggested.   Moving the code to the Paint event works.   Also, i tried the ForceQueue you suggested but it didn't do anything (button didn't show).  Pretty sure it is due to my lack of ability (I just put that line of code in the Show event verbatim).

Comment: Meant to ask, the deal with "this" vs "Form1".  Is it just bad form to use Form1 like that?  In case you change the name of the form sometime?  Just want to know why it matters.  Thank you!

Comment: "*Moving the code to the Paint event works*" - NEVER perform non-painting operations in a Paint event! "*i tried the ForceQueue you suggested but it didn't do anything*" - did you verify that the lambda was actually getting called? It should have been. `ForceQueue()` is asynchronous, the lambda should have been called once execution flow returned to the main UI loop. If it didn't, that is a bug that needs to be reported to Embarcadero. "*Is it just bad form to use Form1 like that?*" - yes. A Form object should NEVER rely on a global Form pointer, ALWAYS on its own `this` pointer.

Comment: I don't know how to verify if a lambda was called.  But, I changed the code like this and it ran:  TThread::ForceQueue(nullptr, [this](){ShowMessage("Hi");});  Next I changed a line of code from Form1->cmbBox1->Items->Add("Show All"); to this->cmbBox1->Items->Add("Show All"); and it crashes.  This is in the FormShow event.   So, I decide to move ALL my startup code to a new subroutine that I call like this:  TThread::ForceQueue(nullptr, [this](){StartupCode();});     This runs fine - I'm assuming after the form is completely constructed and shown.  I'm in over my head but I'm working on it.

Comment: p.s.  This approach fails on Windows.  I get "E2451 Undefined symbol 'nullptr' in the IDE when it hits TThread::ForceQueue(nullptr, [this](){StartupCode();});   Works fine on Android and iOS.

Comment: That means you are using the "classic" 32-bit compiler ([bcc32](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32)) instead of a newer [Clang-based](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers) compiler ([bcc32c](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32C) or [bcc64](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC64)). `nullptr` is a keyword added in C++11. Use `NULL` instead in the classic compiler. The iOS and Android compilers are Clang-based compilers.

Comment: Changing to NULL didn't work so I went to project options and under C++ Compiler I set "Use 'classic' Borland compiler" to false.  Code compiles but when it runs I get "External exception EEFFACE".  So, for now I'm using #ifdef blocks to run the TThread code on mobile and just call StartupCode() from FormShow in window for now.

Comment: using NULL works fine for me. EEFFACE means a C++ exception is being thrown that you are not catching before it enters into the Delphi-based RTL and is caught in there. And the BCC32C compiler does have some known compatibility issues in VCL projects, maybe it does in FMX projects too, I'm not sure.